# Render annotation in timeseries chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chartjs-plugin-annotation

What's the correct configuration to add a line annotation to a [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) chart where the x-axis is of the 'timeseries' type?

Without the `timeseries` the following code works as expected.

```js
function average(ctx) {
  const values = ctx.chart.data.datasets[0].data;
  return values.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / values.length;
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chart');

const mean = {
  type: 'line',
  drawTime: 'afterDraw',
  label: {
    display: true,
    content: (ctx) => average(ctx).toFixed(2),
   },
   scaleID: 'y',
   value: (ctx) => average(ctx)
 };

const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
     labels:   ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
     datasets: [
       { data: [42, 129, 53, 55, 52, 62, 68, 55, 61, 58, 66, 63, 53, 69] }
     ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {,
       annotation: {
         annotations: {
          mean
         }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[image: working chart]

However, when I introduce the `timeseries`

```js
function average(ctx) {
  const values = ctx.chart.data.datasets[0].data;
  return values.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / values.length;
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chart');

const mean = {
  type: 'line',
  drawTime: 'afterDraw',
  label: {
    display: true,
    content: (ctx) => average(ctx).toFixed(2),
   },
   scaleID: 'y',
   value: (ctx) => average(ctx)
 };

const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [ 
        { x: '2023-04-03 10:32:09', y: 42 },
        { x: '2023-04-03 10:32:16', y: 129 },
        { x: '2023-04-03 10:32:29', y: 53 },
        { x: '2023-04-03 10:32:37', y: 55 },
        { x: '2023-04-03 10:32:44', y: 52 },
        { x: '2023-04-03 10:32:51', y: 62 },
        { x: '2023-04-03 10:33:04', y: 68 },
        { x: '2023-04-03 10:33:12', y: 55 },
        { x: '2023-04-03 10:33:26', y: 61 },
        { x: '2023-04-03 10:34:11', y: 58 },
        { x: '2023-04-03 10:34:27', y: 66 },
        { x: '2023-04-03 10:34:34', y: 63 },
        { x: '2023-04-03 10:34:48', y: 53 },
        { x: '2023-04-03 10:34:55', y: 69 } ]
      },
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: { 
        type: 'timeseries',
        time: { unit: 'hour' },
        ticks: { beginAtZero: true } 
      }
    },
    plugins: {
       annotation: {
         annotations: {
          mean
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[image]

The annotation is not rendered.

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the average function. When you are using "data points" (objects as data), you have to use the property of the object which is representing the Y data.

```
function average(ctx) {
  const values = ctx.chart.data.datasets[0].data;
  // you have to use b.y to get the y value and not simply b which is an object
  return values.reduce((a, b) => a + b.y, 0) / values.length;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should import the date adapter library as mentioned in the [documentation]

> The time scale requires both a date library and a corresponding adapter to be present. Please choose from the available adapters.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

While in the annotation which you are drawing a line indicating the average,

`b` is an object, instead, I believe that you should get the value with `b.y`.

```js
function average(ctx) {
  const values = ctx.chart.data.datasets[0].data;
  return values.reduce((a, b) => a + b.y, 0) / values.length;
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-pq1nb4?file=index.html)